# XCAssets is not copied to application bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, xcasset

I am having a problem with XCAssets. I created a custom XCAssets file with icons inside. I get the image from the file like this:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"deniedOverlay"];
```

So, now the problem. The files aren't copied to the .app file, so I get blank images. XCAssets file is added to "Copy Bundle Resources". I can't fix this problem myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the xcassets catalog to the correct target?

Comment: I have this issue as well in Xcode 7 beta creating a loadable bundle.  The `actool` displays no errors and appears to attempt to compile the `.xcassets` file directly into the build directory.  However nothing appears and no errors are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this link it might help you in using xcassets.

[How to use Image.xcassets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_36Y6rDcKP0&list=PLXCowKcXAVgrCe2Lezv0acRf4adQLshv2)

Sorry for not providing audio in the video. But it might help you in solving you problem.